# How to Split Flow in Power Automate

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate, azure-boards

I use Power Automate and Azure Boards. I am created 7 cloud flows. Now when i created initiative in azure boards all threads start firing at the same time and I have many child tasks. How do I set up my flows so that only the first should be "on create", the rest should be on transition between flow (status change) ?
This my flow:
[image]

Comment: Can you please show us some screenshots or something that better illustrates your problem?

Comment: I am upgrade my question

Comment: Sorry but that barely helps. What are the triggers on each flow? What does each flow do? It’s not clear as to what we’re mean to to be helping you with. You need to elaborate a lot more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you need to modify the trigger of your Power Automate flow.

> How do I set up my flows so that only the first should be "on create"

You can set the trigger: **When a work item is created**

For example:

[image]

In this case, the flow will be triggered when creating work item.

> the rest should be on transition between flow (status change) ?

You can set the trigger: **When a work item is updated**

[image]

Comment: If i set the trigger "When a work item is updated, this trigger will be work when i change "State" ?